# Trying to learn SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement that strings the name together. The issue is that I want to put a period after the middle initial but when it is blank the period is after the firstname. Here is the select

```
select LTrim(RTrim(FirstName + ' ' + Left(MiddleName,1))) + '. ' + LastName as FullName,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a case

```
select LTrim(RTrim(FirstName + ' ' + case when isnull(MiddleName,'')='' then else Left(MiddleName,1))) + '. ' end + LastName as FullName,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Case` statement to check if the string is not empty

```
select LTrim(RTrim(FirstName + ' ' + Left(MiddleName,1)))  +
case when  Left(MiddleName,1) <> '' then '. ' else '' end + LastName as FullName,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the existance of the `MiddleName` and only include your period if its not null

```
SELECT
  LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName + ' ' +  IIF(ISNULL(MiddleName,'')<>'',LEFT(MiddleName,1) + '.', ''))) + ' ' + LastName as FullName
```